# Preferred approach with int values while adding 64-bit support to iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, 64-bit

I am updating an old iOS app that does not support 64-bit architectures.

From Apple's conversion procedure, it looks like it converts "int and unsigned int to NSInteger and NSUInteger, respectively."  However, when doing this, I would end up with a lot of casting to longs during formatting, as shown below.  I would be concerned about the performance on 32-bit architectures because of all of the casting to long.

```
//old
NSInteger myIntValue = 5;
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myIntValue];

//new
NSInteger myIntValue = 5;
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)myIntValue];
```

An alternative would be to replace my usages of NSInteger with int, so that they remain 4-byte values, so I do not need to cast to long when formatting myIntValue.

```
//old
NSInteger myIntValue = 5;
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myIntValue];

//new
int myIntValue = 5;
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myIntValue];
```

Should the latter method be avoided for any particular reason, assuming that items that change from NSInteger to int will be guaranteed to fit inside a 4-byte int?

Comment: Another option: `NSString *str = [@(someNSIntegerValue) stringValue];`.

Answer (score 0):

Those castings are the *only way* to format strings when compiling for both 32- **and** 64-bit as the alternative is worse (in my opinion):

```
#if __LP64__
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", myIntValue];
#else
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myIntValue];
#endif
```

There are no significant performance issues to worry about with the cast as it's just a matter of how much space is made on the stack and maybe some sign-extension.  Minor stuff.

Comment: Wouldn't the latter method (I just added sample code) also compile for both 32- and 64-bit architectures?

Comment: @jkh Yes, but the whole point is to move away from `int` towards `NSInteger` (and it will still require a `cast` as using a literal like that isn't a realistic example).